# VS2010: Create a custom build rule to run on all files of a given filetype in a given folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, target

So I have a VS2010 project which contains a folder called "Levels" with "Level1.xml", "Level2.xml", etc. I have a custom build tool I want to run on these XML files, and so far, I've been individually modifying the properties of each file in VS2010, setting the Configuration Properties > Item Type to "Custom Build Tool", and then copy-pasting the exact same values into the "Command Line" / "Description" / "Outputs" parameters in the custom build tool property page.

This is, of course, a terrible practice.

I believe that adding a new Target to the .vcxproj should help, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx , but I've found absolutely no way to say "Run the following step on all items that match these given rules". How can I solve this?

Comment: Presumably the tool that you run on those files produces some other files as output? If so, then you should make sure that your target has `Outputs` correctly specified, and whatever target consumes your generated files also declares its `Inputs` - and then MSBuild should make note of that dependency and take care of everything. Can you describe the scenario in more detail?